# Will Nexus 5 be allowed to update to Android L?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I'm planning to buy a Nexus 5 next month, but before that I'd like to know if I will be allowed to update it to the next Android version, when it get released, that for now is being called Android L.

Comment: Every Nexus device so far has gotten at least two major android updates and also since the Android L Preview runs on the Nexus 5 so it is definitely getting the full update when it is ready.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version for nexus 5 is 4.4.4. Once L is ready to be released to users, you will be allowed to update.

Currently L developer preview is available.

Comment: Agree. The Nexus 5, Nexus 7 (2013), and (still pending) Nexus 9 are all Google/Android dev. platforms. They will receive any new releases *soon after* it is released (along with a new platform/device).

Answer (score 0):

There's a developer build of Android L available for both Nexus 5 and Nexus 7, since they're "development" devices I think you can safely assume that the stable images will be released for them when the time comes. Honestly the development build is pretty stable and you could use it before "proper" release, at least I think so.